# Can we find the location of the built-in method calls in python profiling?

Tags: python, cprofile

When I profile my python code using cProfile, there are lots of {built-in method...} taking most of the time. They may be third party APIs or my C/Fortran-extensions. Question is that can we easily find where these methods were called in the python script? Thanks!